# spark scala: count occurrence key - pair values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Scala and need help to figure out how to count occurrence of key-pair values. I have an input text files as follows:

```
a: b
b: c
c: a,b,d
d: b,c
e: b
```

I wanted to count occurrence of each values, so it should be something like:

```
a | b | c| d| e| 
0   4   2  1  0
```

What I was thinking of doing is splitting each line and each key, value pairs into something like this:

```
a,b
b,c
c,a
c,b
c,d
d,b
d,c
e,b
```

and then count based on the same key.

What I have so far is:

```
val links = sc.textFile("input.txt")
 val test = links.flatMap(line => line.split(":").map(row => row.split("\\s+")
```

Any ideas what to do next or reference I can see would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file:

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ":").csv("/path/to/file").toDF("key", "value")
```

Split records

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val long = df.withColumn("value", explode(split(trim($"value"), ",")))
```

And either aggregate

```
long.groupBy("value").count.show
```

or pivot

```
long.groupBy().pivot($"value").count.show
```